# Netcat over Javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, tcp

I'm working under one cloud solution, that's allow user to print receipts on ESC/POS printer. So it's actually pretty easy to print on it like

```
echo "Hello world!" | nc 192.168.1.37 9100
```

But, I need to do the same with from user's browser. So i've tried like this:

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://IPAddress:Port');

connection.onopen = function () {
  connection.send('Ping'); // Send the message 'Ping' to the server
};
```

And almost done, but WS send whole stack of HTTP headers starts with

```
 GET / HTTP/1.1 
 ...
```

Is there way to send it without headers? Or other way to send data to printer?

Answer (score 2):

netcat or nc use TCP protocol and it doesn't use header like "POST /1 HTTP/1.1\r\n" like http requests do. You are probably thinking about using [net.Socket()](https://gist.github.com/tedmiston/5935757) and not [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)
I do not want to confuse you because you aim to use javascript in browser, but i used net.Socket() successfully with node.js. The point of this comment is, that you aim to establish TCP connection and not WS.

Comment: it’s not about server side solution. There lot of more easier ways to make that task without node. The original question was about browser side. So I dont find any solution except using some “proxy” hardware or middleware

Comment: I tried to only explain, that he wants to make pure TCP connection and not WebSocket.

Answer (score 1):

I think that HTTP always starts sending GET and HTTP Headers.
Maybe you can use some old technology like signed Java Applets or Flash.
In addition, you can download a binary file to the client PC to communicate.